# How do I ensure that the colour of my navigation bar does not change when I return back to home page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my home page and my navigation bar initially (image attached ) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTEIw.png)

but when I go to another page and return back to this page, the colour of navigation bar changes (image attached):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeO9r.png)

How do I make sure it does not change

this is my code:

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: "#00428b" }}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography
                variant="body1"
                component="div"
                style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
              >
                Community League Financial Proficiency Self Assessment Tool
              </Typography>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={() => {
                  userCtx.logout();
                }}
              >
                Logout
              </Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </Box>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you  can set style for Typography.          <Typography variant="body1" component="div" style={{ flexGrow: 1, color: "white" }}>
            Community League Financial Proficiency Self Assessment Tool
          </Typography>